getComputedStyle wrong for placeholder on some mobile devices
This seems like a browser bug to me but I couldn't find anyone else seeing the same problem. It seems like getComputedStyle isn't getting the right font-size for an input placeholder for some mobile browsers.
In my example below the placeholder font-size is set to 11px. In some mobile browsers, getComputedStyle thinks the placeholder's font size is 16px.
I've tested this on:

iPhone 16 in Safari and Chrome: 16px

Samsung Galaxy S22 in Chrome: 16px

Samsung Galaxy S22 in Firefox: 11px

Chrome and Firefox on Win11: 11px


See this jsfiddle, or snippet below:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<style>
.form-control::placeholder {
  font-size: 11px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
function updatePlaceholderLength(el) {
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    var placeholderFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(el, '::placeholder').fontSize;
    
   document.querySelector('.debug-info-js').textContent = 'placeholder font size: ' + placeholderFontSize;
}

updatePlaceholderLength(document.getElementById('whatever'));
</script>

<div class="container">
  <label class="control-label" for="whatever">Check it out</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="whatever" type="text" placeholder="Here is my placeholder.">
  <hr>
  <pre class="debug-info-js"></pre>
</div>

Just wondering if anyone has any info on this... is it a known bug/limitation? Is this by design? Is there any workaround to get the right font-size?
Tried adding !important to the font-size declaration which of course didn't work... I have no idea what else I can do.

Are you certain bootstrap is not doing this? Bootstrap has a way of over riding styles...

Mobile browsers tend to have more aggressive defaults to provide a minimal readability. You may try to disable defaults by applying appearance:none - or just use 16px for all browsers. I doubt getComputedStyles() returns a wrong value.

Accirding to MDN the current standard is for ::before and ::after to be supported but the draft standard doesn't have this restriction so It's possible some browsers have not yet implemented the draft. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

@herrstrietzel I tried out appearance: none on the field and placeholder individually as well as on both. Didn't fix it but thanks for the suggestion. I may end up just having the placeholder use the same font size as the input.

@AHaworth nice find there on MDN. I'm not sure that note on MDN is up to date though--I see this 2016 working draft explicitly stating ::before and ::after https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-cssom-1-20160317/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle ...while the 2021 draft doesn't https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle Honestly though reading these drafts hurts my brain and it's possible I just don't understand it at all. I might submit Chrome and Safari bugs and see what happens. Thank you!

Well, I guess drafts are drafts.
